# JList not responding to listModel.addElement(

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a JList in my Java Swing application and when a user clicks a button, the list clears and the contents reset as follows:

```
public void reset(ArrayList<String> content) {
    listModel.removeAllElements();
    System.out.println(content.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++) {
       listModel.addElement(content.get(i));
       System.out.println("Added element " + content.get(i));
   }
}
```

The list is initialized as follows

```
listModel = new DefaultListModel();
list = new JList(listModel);
```

However there is a problem. The list clears (before the reset, there was other content. This content does go away), but the new content does not show up. And, from the output, I can see that 6 elements have been added. But they do not show up in the list. Why is this?

Comment: hmm ... should work (you see the println?) - seems the error is elsewhere (might a crazy shadow, as @trashgod guessed), best to show a SSCCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However there is a problem. The list clears (before the reset, there
>   was other content. This content does go away), but the new content
>   does not show up. And, from the output, I can see that 6 elements have
>   been added. But they do not show up in the list. Why is this?

nobody knows, only [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) could be issue, be sure that all events would be dode on EDT, otherwise for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), for example

EDIT

added String instances requested by @Robin

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListString extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    private int i = 01;

    public ListString() {
        model.addElement(("one" + i++));
        model.addElement(("two" + i++));
        model.addElement(("three" + i++));
        model.addElement(("four" + i++));
        JList list = new JList(model);
        add(new JScrollPane(list));
        JButton btn = new JButton("Remove All Rows :");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                model.removeAllElements();
            }
        });
        add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Add New Rows:");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                model.addElement(("one" + i++));
                model.addElement(("two" + i++));
                model.addElement(("three" + i++));
                model.addElement(("four" + i++));
            }
        });
        add(btn1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("List.selectionBackground", Color.red);
        ListString frame = new ListString();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

with rendering JPanel inside JScrollPane requested by @trashgod

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListPanel extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    private int i = 01;

    public ListPanel() {
        model.addElement(createPanel("one" + i++));
        model.addElement(createPanel("two" + i++));
        model.addElement(createPanel("three" + i++));
        model.addElement(createPanel("four" + i++));
        JList list = new JList(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new PanelRenderer());
        add(new JScrollPane(list));
        JButton btn = new JButton("Remove All Rows :");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                model.removeAllElements();
            }
        });
        add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Add New Rows:");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                model.addElement(createPanel("one" + i++));
                model.addElement(createPanel("two" + i++));
                model.addElement(createPanel("three" + i++));
                model.addElement(createPanel("four" + i++));
            }
        });
        add(btn1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static JPanel createPanel(String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Item: "));
        panel.add(new JLabel(text));
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("List.selectionBackground", Color.red);
        ListPanel frame = new ListPanel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class PanelRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JPanel renderer = (JPanel) value;
            renderer.setBackground(isSelected ? list.getSelectionBackground() : list.getBackground());
            return renderer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for demonstrating that the view sees model updates automatically; I suspect CodeGuy may be updating a shadow model. Sorry if I'm overlooking `invikeLater()`. :-)

Comment: Why are you adding the `JPanel` instances yo your model ... it might work but not the best sample code. Better to just add the `String` instances to your model and let the renderer do the work

Comment: I thought adding `JPanel` instances to the model was a feature! :-) May add a scroll pane for he (expanding) list?

Comment: nudging to remove the panels-as-data entirely, it's a no-no-ever ... nevertheless such bad practice will find followers :-)

Comment: @kleopatra code example demonstrated add/remove/(modify == removed) Items in JList, even way couldn't be correct (I'm using JPanel in JComboBox, JTable and JList) still I'm waiting to find out any bug in this processes

Comment: you _know_ that you shouldn't store components in the model (instead store _data_ and render those in a custom renderer) - so why do you here?