# JList not updating when set to new DefaultListModel

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel,file_list_panel;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu mnNewMenu1,mnNewMenu2,mnNewMenu3;
    private JMenuItem mt1,mt2,mt3;
    private JPanel right,left ,bottom;
    private JSplitPane spver ,sphor;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JLabel label;
    private JList<String> list_1;
    private JScrollPane jscroll_list;
    private DefaultListModel listmodel_1 = new DefaultListModel();


    public MainMenu() {




    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    int intValue = Integer.parseInt( "EEEEEE",16);
    Color aColor = new Color( intValue );
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.background", new Color(230, 216, 174));
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.WHITE); 
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.contentAreaColor",aColor ); 
    UIManager.put("TabbedPane.focus", Color.WHITE); 

    setTitle("Main Menu");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //setBounds(100, 100, 848, 680);
    //setLocation(10, 10);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // set jFrame alignment to center

    //parent(first) panel 
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    //Main Menu BAR
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setFont(new Font("Tekton Pro Ext", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //Menu 1
    mnNewMenu1 = new JMenu("New menu");
    menuBar.add(mnNewMenu1);
    //Menu 1 MenuItem 1

    mt1 = new JMenuItem("Browse New Project");
    mt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        BrowseScreen frame = new BrowseScreen();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }


    });


    mnNewMenu1.add(mt1);




    //second panel
    panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    spver =new  JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
    spver.setDividerLocation(500);
    spver.setEnabled(false);

    bottom=new JPanel();
    sphor =new  JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
    sphor.setEnabled(false);
    spver.setTopComponent(sphor);
    spver.setBottomComponent(bottom);
    bottom.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(spver);

    sphor.setDividerLocation(180);
    left =new JPanel();
    right =new JPanel();
    sphor.setRightComponent(right);
    right.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);

    JPanel tab1 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("fffa", tab1);
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

    JPanel tab2 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("TAB1", tab2);
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);



    right.add(tabbedPane);
    sphor.setLeftComponent(left);
    left.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    file_list_panel= new JPanel();
    file_list_panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    file_list_panel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    label = new JLabel("Java Files of Project");
    label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    label.setFont(new Font("Garamond", Font.BOLD, 14));
    file_list_panel.add(label);
    left.add(file_list_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    list_1 = new JList<String>(listmodel_1);



    jscroll_list = new JScrollPane(list_1);
    left.add(jscroll_list, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }
    public  void setList(Vector<String> files){
        listmodel_1.removeAllElements();
        list_1.removeAll();
        for(int i=0;i<files.size();i++)
            listmodel_1. addElement(files.elementAt(i));
        list_1.setModel(listmodel_1);
        this.invalidate();
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
    }

}
```

setList is called from the browse window before it calls setVisible(false);
ie . this methods gets called when the browse window disappears .. it does all the things in method but does not update it in the MainMenu 
    public void setFileList(){
            MainMenu mm= new MainMenu();
            mm.setList(java_files);
        }

list_1 -JList listmodel_1=DefaultListModel

i've tried to refreshing the frame but does not refresh after adding the new list to the Main Window ...

before JList is updated im browsing the the files in another window then it is set to setVisible(false) then MainMenu gets focused and calls the setList method but its not changing

Comment: [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13905419/714968)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you are creating a new `JList` and associating your model with it, but this has no effect on the `JList` that is on the screen

```
public  void setList(Vector<String> files){
    // Good...
    listmodel_1.removeAllElements();
    // Not required, has nothing to do with the items in the list
    //list_1.removeAll();
    // Good
    for(int i=0;i<files.size();i++)
        listmodel_1. addElement(files.elementAt(i));
    // This here is your problem
    //list_1=new JList<String>(listmodel_1);
    // Because I have no idea what model list_1 is actually using...
    list_1.setModel(listmodel_1);
    //list_1.setSelectedIndex(0);
    //this.invalidate();
    //this.validate();
    //this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help .. I'm still not getting any changes in my main JFrame when i tried your code ... i dont know what im doing wrong here. but when i add this.setVisible(true) it loads another window with the new list but the old window is still there then i added a this.setVisible(false) before this.setVisible(true) but still getting the old Main Window

Comment: You need to update you're question with a runnable example, it looks like you are shadowing your variables all over the place

Comment: thanks for your reply i've posted the all of the MainMenu JFrame code

Comment: setList is called from the BrowseWindow before it is setVisible(false) all the thing in setList is done but but does not update it ... only way to update it is by calling the Main Menu setVisible(true) statement but the old window does not go away

Comment: How does `BrowserScreen` know what to update, you've not passed a reference of your `MainMenu` to it.  I bet your creating a new instance in `BrowserScreen`...

Comment: yes .. you are right ! im so stupid that ive not passed a reference of the MainMenu and use it to call setList() rather im initiating a new MainMenu Object and call its setList() method .... Thank you so much for your help ... passing a reference did the trick !! :)

Answer (score 5):

You're creating a new `JList<String>` and copying the reference to your instance variable - but you're neither removing the old `JList` from the frame, nor adding the new one. Just changing the variable won't do that.

Rather than creating a new `JList<String>`, why don't you just replace the model of the existing one? Remove this line:

```
list_1=new JList<String>(listmodel_1);
```

and you may find it just works. (You're already setting the model in the subsequent line...)

Comment: I did it the way you are telling me earlier after when it did not do what it suppose to i've tried adding stuff like list_1=new JList<String>(listmodel_1);

Comment: @mouse: No, I specifically said to *remove* that line. If there are still problems, you need to be specific. "Did not do what it suppose to" does not describe the problem.

Comment: i meant that it does not update the jlist on the main Window. Main Menu updates if i call its setVisible(true) ... but this will create double windows with old and new Main Windows

Comment: @mouse: I suggest you edit your question with a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: thanks for your help. i did managed to get the answer. the problem was that ive not passed a reference the Main window object rather i created a new object of it and called its setList method. Thank again :)